# Listagg Overflow function implementation (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using `LISTAGG` function for my query, however, it returned an `ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long` error. So I googled that error and found out I can use `ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE` and I implemented that into my SQL but now it generates `missing right parenthesis` error and I can't seem to figure out why?

---

My query

```
SELECT DISTINCT cust_id, acct_no, state, language_indicator, billing_system, market_code,
EMAIL_ADDR, DATE_OF_CHANGE, TO_CHAR(DATE_LOADED, 'DD-MM-YYYY') DATE_LOADED, 
(SELECT LISTAGG( SUBSTR(mtn, 7, 4),'<br>' ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE '***' )
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cust_id || acct_no) mtnlist
FROM process.feature WHERE date_loaded BETWEEN TO_DATE('02-08-2018','MM-dd-yyyy')
AND TO_DATE('02-09-2018', 'MM-dd-yyyy') AND cust_id = ffsr.cust_id
AND acct_no = ffsr.acct_no AND filename = 'FEATURE.VB2B.201802090040'
GROUP BY cust_id||acct_no) mtnlist
FROM process.feature ffsr WHERE date_loaded BETWEEN TO_DATE('02-08-2018','MM-dd-yyyy')
AND TO_DATE('02-09-2018','MM-dd-yyyy') AND cust_id BETWEEN 0542185146 AND 0942025571
AND src_ind = 'B' AND filename = 'FEATURE.VB2B.201802090040'
AND letter_type = 'FA' ORDER BY cust_id;
```

Comment: `on overflow` is only available since Oracle 12.2

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name omg :(!! Thanks! Now i have to find a new way

Answer (score 4):

With a little bit of help by XML, you might get it work. Example is based on HR schema.

```
SQL> select
  2    listagg(s.department_name, ',') within group (order by null) result
  3  from departments s, departments d;
from departments s, departments d
     *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long


SQL>
SQL> select
  2  rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement (e, s.department_name || ',')).extract
  3    ('//text()').getclobval(), ',') result
  4  from departments s, departments d;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Administration,Administration,Administration,Administration,Administration,Admin

SQL>
```

Comment: Nice solution. You may even use the *order_by_clause* in `XMLAgg` to controll the order in the same way as in `listagg`.

Comment: Thank you, @Marmite. Yes, ORDER BY could have been used. Honestly, I didn't notice it in such an unformatted original code, but paid attention to ORA-01489 error instead.

Comment: can we use xmlagg instead of listagg **only if** ORA-01489 will be thrown?

Comment: You can use XMLAGG any time you want. Though, as you can see, it is quite a lot more complex than a simple LISTAGG function, so I prefer *simple* option over the opposite one **if it works OK**.

Comment: hi, can u help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72413894/ora-01489-result-of-string-concatenation-is-too-long-in-oracle

Answer (score 2):

This demo sourced from livesql.oracle.com

```
-- Create table with 93 strings of different lengths, plus one NULL string. Notice the only ASCII character not used is '!', so I will use it as a delimiter in LISTAGG.
create table strings as 
with letters as ( 
  select level num, 
  chr(ascii('!')+level) let 
  from dual 
  connect by level <= 126 - ascii('!') 
  union all 
  select 1, null from dual 
) 
select rpad(let,num,let) str from letters;

-- Note the use of LENGTHB to get the length in bytes, not characters.
  select str,   
  sum(lengthb(str)+1) over(order by str rows unbounded preceding) - 1 cumul_lengthb,   
  sum(lengthb(str)+1) over() - 1 total_lengthb,   
  count(*) over() num_values   
  from strings   
  where str is not null;

-- This statement implements the ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE WITH COUNT option of LISTAGG in 12.2. If there is no overflow, the result is the same as a normal LISTAGG.
select listagg(str, '!') within group(order by str) || 
  case when max(total_lengthb) > 4000 then 
    '! ... (' || (max(num_values) - count(*)) || ')' 
  end str_list 
from ( 
  select str, 
  sum(lengthb(str)+1) over(order by str) - 1 cumul_lengthb, 
  sum(lengthb(str)+1) over() - 1 total_lengthb, 
  count(*) over() num_values 
  from strings 
  where str is not null 
) 
where total_lengthb <= 4000 
   or cumul_lengthb <= 4000 - length('! ... (' || num_values || ')');
```

Comment: You said: "This statement implements the ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE WITH COUNT option ...". Where is that *option* in code you posted?

Comment: @Littlefoot Yes, the last query works in that way that if the total length of the concatenated strings is higher than the limit of 4000 bytes, it considers only limited number of rows (so that the cumulated length is <= 4000) and adds the suffix that the list was truncated including the information how many rows were ommited. A small addaption will be required if this concept should be used with `GROUP BY` (simple adding `partition by group columns` in the middle query). @Conner may by you should add few words of explanation to the answer...

Comment: For @Littlefoot - in 12.2, the truncate facilities in LISTAGG allow you to truncate the long text but also do things like (a) add some characters to indicate that you truncate (eg eliipses), and (b) add a count of the number of characters that we had to truncate off.  The script above allows you to implement the count should it be needed.

Comment: Connor & @Marmite, I'm afraid you didn't understand what I said. As you said that "*this statement implements ...*", I expected to actually *see* it being implemented. Something like `select listagg(some_col, ',' on overflow truncate '' without count) within group(order by rownum) from ...`, but there's no such a statement in your example.

Comment: If you want "on overflow truncate" in the SQL itself...you have to upgrade to 12.2.  Simple as that.  If you want to emulate it, ie, so your concatenations do not fail with an error, then you can use the SQL provided.

Comment: Hi Connor, can u help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72415110/missing-right-parenthesis-error-for-listagg-on-overflow-truncate/