# Missing right parenthesis error for LISTAGG ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, listagg

I am using `ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE` logic to implement `LISTAGG` function.

But while implementing like below, I am getting error as

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Here is the query

```
SELECT IMG.IMG_TYPE, LISTAGG(TO_CHAR(IMG.IMG_NAME), ' ' ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE )
 WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY IMG.IMG_TYPE) AS IMAGES
      FROM TBL_VSAT_MST_DETAIL VT 
        INNER JOIN TBL_VSAT_IMAGE_DETAIL IMG ON VT.VSAT_DETAIL_ID = 2414
        WHERE VT.SAP_ID = 'I-OR-GCHP-ENB-9031'
    AND VT.CANDIDATE_ID = 'C1'
        GROUP BY IMG.IMG_TYPE;
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: What is your Oracle version?

Comment: version is `4.1.0.19`

Comment: This cannot be Oracle version. Try running this query - ``SELECT * FROM V$VERSION` and share the result.

Comment: something like `Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production` and `PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production`

Comment: On Overflow Truncate is only available from Oracle 12C. For Oracle 11G use the link I shared.

Comment: actually, Overflow truncate is what i used for my error. my main issue is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72413894/ora-01489-result-of-string-concatenation-is-too-long-in-oracle

Comment: Just check the first answer in the link. That will solve your problem.

Comment: I tired but it was not working. could you help me in that issue ? Please that will save my weekend

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245124/discussion-between-nad-and-ankit-bajpai).

Comment: i tried like this, but no image is displaying.. `SELECT IMG.IMG_TYPE, RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,IMG.IMG_NAME,',').EXTRACT('//text()')
            ORDER BY IMG.IMG_NAME).GetClobVal(),',') AS IMAGES
-- within group(order by IMG.IMG_TYPE) IMAGES
            FROM TBL_VSAT_MST_DETAIL VT 
            INNER JOIN TBL_VSAT_IMAGE_DETAIL IMG ON VT.VSAT_DETAIL_ID = IMG.IMG_ID --IMG.IMG_ID
            WHERE VT.SAP_ID = P_SAPID
            AND VT.CANDIDATE_ID = P_CANDIDATEID
            GROUP BY IMG.IMG_TYPE; `

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for the same?

Comment: here is the fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6f21ab556908f13b4d041d82bf42e0bc

Comment: Please create table and insert some sample data also.

Comment: can we connect on chat ?

Comment: Sure. Lets continue there.

Comment: Can you update your select statement to - `RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,IMG.IMG_NAME || ',').EXTRACT('//text()')
            ORDER BY IMG.IMG_NAME).GetClobVal(),',')`

Comment: Oracle 11.2 is almost 13 years old. You should consider an upgrade.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: please let me know how to tackle this

Comment: How to tackle an upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE` is only available since Oracle 12c, which got released about nine years ago. Latest version is 21c. You should consider an upgrade.

Anyway, your query makes it seems as if you were inner joining the tables, while you are actually cross joining them. You look at certain TBL_VSAT_MST_DETAIL rows, and to each of these you join all TBL_VSAT_IMAGE_DETAIL rows.

This is what you have, written with a proper join clause:

```
SELECT
  img.img_type,
  LISTAGG(TO_CHAR(img.img_name), ' ' ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE )
    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY img.img_type) AS images
FROM tbl_vsat_mst_detail vt 
CROSS JOIN tbl_vsat_image_detail img
WHERE vt.sap_id = 'I-OR-GCHP-ENB-9031'
  AND vt.candidate_id = 'C1'
  AND vt.vsat_detail_id = 2414
GROUP BY img.img_type;
```

I suppose - but I can only guess here, as I don't even know what your tables look like exactly - that you want something like this:

```
SELECT
  img.img_type,
  LISTAGG(img.img_name, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY img.img_name) AS images
FROM tbl_vsat_image_detail img
WHERE img.vsat_id IN
(
  SELECT vt.vsat_id
  FROM tbl_vsat_mst_detail vt 
  WHERE vt.sap_id = 'I-OR-GCHP-ENB-9031'
    AND vt.candidate_id = 'C1'
    AND vt.vsat_detail_id = 2414
)
GROUP BY img.img_type
ORDER BY img.img_type;
```

Maybe without the cartesian join, there is no overflow anymore and the problem is solved for the moment.

Comment: Will update you once I got in laptop.

Comment: I m using first answer of yours and getting error as `Error(1247,48): PL/SQL: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`

Comment: First answer? You mean the first query I am showing? This is not a solution, but your query written properly, as I've explained above it. I've told you, and 
Ankit Bajpai told you before, that `ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE` does not work in your old Oracle version, which is why you are getting this error message. So, why are you surprised you are getting it? As long as this clause is in your query, you'll get a syntax error in Oracle 11g. And reading that you took that query as a solution, I am beginning to doubt that you read my answer at all. Do you understand what I am explaining in my answer?

Comment: I am telling you not only that the Oracle version is a problem, but that in your query you don't relate the two tables. You select every image, and you select them even multifold. So, my suggestion is to relate the two tables in your query, by some common key. I dont know what this key is, because I don't know your tables. But you should know. I've made up a conecting column vsat_id and imaginge you just want a look up, as you are only selecting columns from the image table. So, you maw want an `IN` or `EXISTS` clause to show images that have a match in the mst_detail table.

Comment: I can't. I don't know your tables. Neither the structure nor their content. I don't even know what you want to achieve. I don't know why the table tbl_vsat_mst_detail is even in your query. It is up to you now to write the query you want. I've given you the information that in your query you don't relate the tables. You know how they are related. So join them or use `EXISTS` or `IN`. If you don't know these clauses yet, read up on them.

Comment: No, I am not available. And even if I had the time, I wouldn't be ready to spend it on this. I've already invested some time to help you and have given you enough information to enable you to write the query If you are still unable to write the query, then that's the way it is. From here you have have two options: Learn SQL yourself (class, book, tutorial) or hire someone to write the query for you.